# Select and merge layers in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

I want to explicitly select multiple layers (by reference, not by name or anything else involving re-searching something I already have a reference to!) and merge them in Adobe's Javascript (aka. Extendscript).

I can set the document's activeLayer, but it won't take an array of layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the LayerSet object which refers to a group of layers including nested LayerSet's [-Photoshop Javascript Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf). You can manipulate all layers within a layer set with a single command like this:

```
LayerSet.merge();
```